# SQL INSERT WEIRD SYNTAX ERROR MYSQL FROM PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

i need help to figure what is wrong with my code. i have this code like this

```
<?php 

include('./config/db.php');

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

$p1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp1']);
$p2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp2']);
$p3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp3']);
$p4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp4']);
$p5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp5']);
$p6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp6']);
$p7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp7']);
$p8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp8']);
$p9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp9']);
$p10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp10']);
$p11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp11']);
$p12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp12']);
$p13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp13']);
$p14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp14']);
$p15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp15']);
$p16 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp16']);
$p17 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp17']);
$p18 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp18']);
$p19 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp19']);
$p20 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp20']);
$p21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp21']);
$p22 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtp22']);

$sql = 
"
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `kualitas_produk`(`responden`,`p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5`,`p6`,`p7`,`p8`,`p9`) VALUES ('','$p1','$p2','$p3','$p4','$p5','$p6','$p7','$p8','$p9');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @LASTID;
INSERT INTO `harga_produk`(`responden`,`p10`,`p11`,`p12`) VALUES (@LASTID,'$p10','$p11','$p12');
INSERT INTO `keputusan_pembelian`(`responden`,`p13`,`p14`,`p15`,`p16`,`p17`,`p18`,`p19`,`p20`,`p21`,`p22`) VALUES (@LASTID, '$p13','$p14','$p15', '$p16','$p17','$p18', '$p19','$p20','$p21', '$p22');
INSERT INTO `recap`(`responden`,`kualitas`,`harga`,`keputusan`) VALUES ('',@LASTID,@LASTID,@LASTID);
COMMIT;
";
```

at this point, i got this error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `kualitas_produk`(`responden`,`p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5`,`p6`,`p7`,`p8' at line 2

here how i execute the query

```
mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
echo "Data Berhasil Ditambahkan";
mysqli_close($db);
```

i already tried to return the $sql variabel for the error, and then copy paste it manually on phpmyadmin, and the code has no error at all..

can someone figure where the problem is? any help will be appreciated

> SOLVED BY M.KHALID READ THE COMMENT BELLOW. THANK YOU GUYS

Comment: How you are executing this query ?

Comment: Does your client library allow multiple statements in a single string? I doubt it from the error being right after the first semicolon.

Comment: You might need to use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for such query

Comment: ok i edit my question. i add how i execute this query

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid AH YES !, i need to use multi_query for this.. THANKS MAN !! U ARE HERO !!

Comment: `multi_query` is a security hole; you would be better off using `mysqli_query` for each statement.  And it lets you check for errors better.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send more than one SQL statement at a time to `mysqli_query`.

`multi_query` is a security hole; you would be better off using `mysqli_query` for each statement.  And it lets you check for errors better.